# Is there anyway to debug css in react native app?

Tags: css, reactjs, debugging, react-native

Debugging css inside chrome makes life easy. I am working on a react native app. Everytime I make any css change I have to refresh my simulator to check it. Is there any other workaround for this ?

Comment: This may help, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools

Comment: you might want to try this. it also have some nice feature when(if) you'll ever need to work with redux https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the most likely answer for you is in fact as I posted in my comment. Chrome debugging using react-devtools: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks !